# integer overflow with a 10 digit number but not an 18 digit number?

Tags: c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
unsigned long long findPeople(double p){
   return ceil(sqrt(2*143545666897673985*log(1/(1-p))));
}
int main(){
   printf("%lld",findPeople(0.5));
}
```

So this is my code. I'm trying to calculate the birthday paradox but with much larger numbers (it's for a maths assignment) and when I use this number (143545666897673985) it works fine, but when I use the other number (1842350265) it comes up with this message:

```
warning: integer overflow in expression of type ‘int’ results in ‘-610266766’ [-Woverflow]
    4 |    return ceil(sqrt(2*1842350265*log(1/(1-p))));
      |                     ~^~~~~~~~~~~
```

I am new to coding and I have no idea what I'm doing. I'm confused as to why it gets an integer overflow for a 10 digit number but not an 18 digit number.

I tried using `unsigned long long` which shouldn't have fixed it and it didn't. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: replace `2` with `2.0` and add `.0` to other numbers as well

Comment: @IłyaBursov thank you so much. That is an annoyingly simple solution.

Comment: Signed integer overflow causes _undefined behavior_. You have no guarantee what will happen. In particular the compiler does not need to diagnose and warn you about it. You simply must assure that it never happens.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yeah I just found this code on some website. I've never done C++ before, I have only done CSS, HTML, basic Javascript and basic C so I don't really know anything about the language. Thanks for the headsup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of a decimal integer literal without suffix is the first out of `int`, `long`, `long long` that can hold the value.

On a usual desktop system where `int` is 32bit wide and either `long` or `long long` is 64bit wide, then

- `2` has type `int`,
- `1842350265` has type `int` and
- `143545666897673985` has type `(long) long`.

In the multiplication with `*` if both sides have type `int` the operation is done in type `int`. If the second operand has type `(long) long`, then operation will be done in `(long) long`.

It just so happens that `2*1842350265`'s mathematical exact value does not fit into a signed 32bit integer (e.g. `int`), but `2*143545666897673985` does fit into a signed 64bit wide integer (e.g. `(long) long`). Therefore signed overflow happens in the first case, but not the latter.

If signed overflow does happen, you cannot rely on the compiler warning you about it. It causes *undefined behavior*, meaning that you will have no guarantee on how the program and compiler will behave. You simply must assure that it never happens.

Since all your other operations in the function act on floating point numbers, not integers, you probably want to use floating point numbers everywhere. E.g. `2.0` has type `double`, as do `143545666897673985.0`, etc.